# add a single "missed" event in a dataframe if there is no event in this day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have something like this as Dataframe:

| Identificator | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2021-05-02 19:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-02 19:48:01 | FAILED |
| ID3 | 2021-05-02 19:47:53 | OK |
| ID1 | 2021-05-03 19:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-03 20:48:01 | OK |
| ID1 | 2021-05-04 19:55:43 | FAILED |
| ID1 | 2021-05-04 20:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-04 19:48:01 | OK |
| ID3 | 2021-05-04 19:47:53 | OK |

As you can see there is no event on 2021-05-03 for ID3. In such cases I would like to add 1 line for ID3 on 021-05-03 00:00:00 with Status "MISSED". So the result to be:

| Identificator | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2021-05-02 19:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-02 19:48:01 | FAILED |
| ID3 | 2021-05-02 19:47:53 | OK |
| ID1 | 2021-05-03 19:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-03 20:48:01 | OK |
| ID3 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 | MISSED |
| ID1 | 2021-05-04 19:55:43 | FAILED |
| ID1 | 2021-05-04 20:55:43 | OK |
| ID2 | 2021-05-04 19:48:01 | OK |
| ID3 | 2021-05-04 19:47:53 | OK |

All IDs will have at least 1 real event in the dataframe, so they can be gathered from the first column.

Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `crosstab` find the 0 count value

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.Identificator,df.Date.dt.date).stack()
df = df.append(s[s==0].reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Status'}).replace(0,'MISSED'))
df
Out[85]: 
  Identificator                 Date  Status
0           ID1  2021-05-02 19:55:43      OK
1           ID2  2021-05-02 19:48:01  FAILED
2           ID3  2021-05-02 19:47:53      OK
3           ID1  2021-05-03 19:55:43      OK
4           ID2  2021-05-03 20:48:01      OK
5           ID1  2021-05-04 19:55:43  FAILED
6           ID1  2021-05-04 20:55:43      OK
7           ID2  2021-05-04 19:48:01      OK
8           ID3  2021-05-04 19:47:53      OK
0           ID3           2021-05-03  MISSED
```

#Note : you can add `sort_values('Date')` at the end

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `set_index` + `reindex` to figure out which dates are missing and then join those back to the original.

First we copy the Id and Date columns and `normalize` since you only care about the dates. Then form the cartesian product of IDs x Dates and see which are missing and set their status to `'Missed'`. Finally concat back and `sort` so everything is in order.

```
df1 = df[['Identificator', 'Date']].copy()
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].dt.normalize()
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['Identificator'].unique(),
                                  pd.date_range(df1.Date.min(), df1.Date.max(), freq='D')],
                                 names=['Identificator', 'Date'])

# DataFrame of IDs with missing dates
df1 = (df1.assign(Status=1)
         .set_index(['Identificator', 'Date'])
         .reindex(idx, fill_value='MISSED')
         .reset_index()
         .query('Status == "MISSED"'))

df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['Date', 'Identificator'])
```

---

```
 Identificator                Date  Status
2           ID3 2021-05-02 19:47:53      OK
1           ID2 2021-05-02 19:48:01  FAILED
0           ID1 2021-05-02 19:55:43      OK
9           ID3 2021-05-03 00:00:00  MISSED
3           ID1 2021-05-03 19:55:43      OK
4           ID2 2021-05-03 20:48:01      OK
8           ID3 2021-05-04 19:47:53      OK
7           ID2 2021-05-04 19:48:01      OK
5           ID1 2021-05-04 19:55:43  FAILED
6           ID1 2021-05-04 20:55:43      OK
```